# Java ConcurrentHashMap initialization

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I am currently reading through the source code of ConcurrentHashMap in jdk1.8, and I find that `initalTable()` method a bit confusing.

```java
public class ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements ConcurrentMap<K,V>, Serializable {
//some fields revolved in this method
transient volatile Node<K,V>[] table;
private transient volatile int sizeCtl;

  private final Node<K,V>[] initTable() {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; int sc;
        while ((tab = table) == null || tab.length == 0) {
            if ((sc = sizeCtl) < 0)
                Thread.yield(); // lost initialization race; just spin
            else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, -1)) {
                try {
                    if ((tab = table) == null || tab.length == 0) {
                        int n = (sc > 0) ? sc : DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        Node<K,V>[] nt = (Node<K,V>[])new Node<?,?>[n];//place 1
                        table = tab = nt;//place 2
                        sc = n - (n >>> 2);
                    }
                } finally {
                    sizeCtl = sc;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return tab;
    }
}
```

So main confusion mainly focused on the following points:

1. Why would we need `while((tab = table) == null || tab.length == 0)` to check both `table` is not null and its length is not 0 and determine whether to continue the loop, so it exits only when both two condition is false. I just cannot think of a situation when the `table` is not null but with a length of 0, since it is initialized in the `else if` block where n is always given a value larger than 0. Then why we need the both rather than only one?

<del>2. The second question is not a problem but rather I just want to check whether my assumption makes sense. So imagine two threads  run subsequently but in a very close manner. The later thread can enter the `else if` block if the earlier one hasn't reach the point of initialization of `table` or place 2 nor has `sizeCtl` been updated, then the second thread will be able to enter the `else if` block, so `table` field will be initialized once more? Will this scenario happens in rare situation? I know this will not affect the correctness of the program but will it happens in some situation?</del>

Hope anyone can give me a clarification. Thanks in advance.

---

**Updated:**
I forgot the fact that one successful CAS operation will swap the `sizeCtl` to -1 which will block other threads from entering the `else if` block, but I am still not clear about why we need two conditions in the `if` and `while`.

Comment: compareAndSwap is atomic; that check ensures that only one thread can enter that block.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for the hint, yeah, I forget the swap, if one thread enter the block `sizeCtl` is already swapped to -1 thus block other thread from entering the block right? But what about the first point? Can you please throw an light on that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to analyze the method `initTable` in isolation. You need to take into account other methods which can also modify `table` and `sizeCtl` fields. There you will notice that e.g. `transfer` decreases `sizeCtl` by one using CAS. I'm not sure if this can lead to `table.length == 0` at any point in time, but note that this whole process is much more complicated and that `initTable` can be called concurrently with resize operation.